# Full Calendar "Time Zone Demo" Example

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, timezone, fullcalendar

I'm trying to learn from this example:

http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.9.1/demos/timezones.html

Please also right click on the web page to view the page source.

The only part that does not work now is as follows:

```
        // when the timezone selector changes, dynamically change the calendar option
        $('#timezone-selector').on('change', function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'timezone', this.value || false);
        });
```

It is trying to change the calendar time display based on the selection of different time zones.

I'm not an expert in Javascript and have tried to find FullCalendar's explanations on this but with no luck.

My question:

1) What can "this.value" possibly mean? "|| false"?

2) In the backend of my web application, I use Java web servlet with hibernate 3.6. For the time input (start time and end time), I use LocalDateTime from Java 8 and store it as UTC timestamp in MySQL. Not sure if this is the best practice for a calendar-based scheduler?

3) Currently, I don't have a timezoneId attached to the timestamp stored in the database yet. But I have created a list for the user to choose from as the FullCalendar example did. Any suggestion on what is the best way to store and later use a timezoneId for this calendar display across different time zones?

For now, I'm thinking that trying to totally imitate FullCalendar's example is not very practical because my database is different from theirs. I'm open to any good suggestions on how to get user's current timezone from his selection, store it in database and later display the proper time value based on any timezone selected by the user on his calendar view page.

Answer (score 2):

If you inspect the timezone select you can see that each option has a value. `this.value` means the on change function will grab the value of the selected option to assign as the timezone. As far as storing your times, they should be stored as UTC timestamp like you are doing. For retrieving the timezone I use [jstz](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) to get the users timezone, its as simple as these two lines.

```
var tz = jstz.determine();
var timezone = tz.name();
```

This is great because you dont have to ask the user for their timezone. Then when I query my database for events I pass in the timezone

```
events: {
    url: "calendarManager.php?request=get&timezone=" + timezone + "&userid=" + userID
},
```

and use php to convert from utc to the users local timezone and return the json encoded events.